# Make all USB drive tags synonyms

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

I suggest all of the following be made synonyms of [usb-drive](/questions/tagged/usb-drive):

- [flash-drives](/questions/tagged/flash-drives)
- [usb-flash-drive](/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive)
- [thumb-drive](/questions/tagged/thumb-drive)
- [pendrive](/questions/tagged/pendrive)

Comment: Hmm, that's not a great tag anyway.  The first three questions under that tag are closed, and the one below that needs to be closed.

Comment: I don't think they are the same. A flash-drive is I suppose a solid state drive. A USB drive is an external device (could be a magnetic platter based HDD) connected via universal serial bus. I don't even know what a thumb drive is but it sounds like what I often hear is referred to as disk-on-key.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite I think the tags [ssd] and [hard-drive] should be used for other cases not referring to the portal storage device. Googling any of these terms will return [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) as the first result. Maybe the master tag should be [usb-flash-drive]?